# Can no longer connect Dialogflow to Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es

My dialogflow chatbot has been unable to respond back with data from a Firebase rtdb. I have included my fulfillment code below. A few days ago, this would respond with the text "test successful" from my db, but now it returns *no response available* and gives the following in console:

> FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Failed to parse access token response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 4"."} "

Does anyone have suggestions on how to debug this? Thanks in advance for your help!

```code
'use strict';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: '<DB-URL-HERE>'
});
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  
    
  function testintent(agent){
    return admin.database().ref().once('value').then((snapshot)=> {
      var myvalue = snapshot.test.val();
      agent.add(myvalue);
    });
  }
   
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Test Intent', testintent);
});
```

Comment: Can you try explicitly defining your service account credentials using [admin.credential.cert()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.credential#cert)?

Comment: I tried explicitly defining my service account credentials and it's working again. Thank you for the suggestion! Would you happen to know what happened with the previous code?

Comment: I'm not quite sure unless we investigate the logs further. You can post your Dialogflow logs in your question if you'd like. But my hunch is that the App Engine Service Account (which does not have Firebase permissions) was used to authenticate when using `admin.credential.applicationDefault()`, since that is the default service account of a cloud function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the authentication problem of Dialogflow to Firebase, instead of using `admin.credential.applicationDefault()` for credentials. Define the correct service account details using [admin.credential.cert()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.credential#cert). There are two ways.

By providing a path to a service account key JSON file:

```
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Or, by providing a service account object inline:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    clientEmail: "foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----<KEY>-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Comment: This works fine!!!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue quickly by explicitly defining credentials as mentioned above.

The underlying culprit was using an older version of firebase-admin. After updating to the newest version, everything worked as expected without needing to explicitly define credentials.