# Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth, firebase-admin

I have a NodeJS Firebase Function that uses firebase-admin sdk. It has been working alright since last year. In the last 2 weeks, the following error started showing in the log:

`Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: 404 page not found`

Could it be an issue with the version of `"firebase-admin": "^7.3.0"` I am using?

Have anyone faced the same issue and can you offer some direction on what might have been the cause?

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you running? If you're using the Node.js 8  version is [deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) and this may be the reason of why you're getting this error. I suggest you to upgrade to a higher version.

Comment: You were right. The issue was with my NodeJS v8. Upgraded to node 10 works well for me.

Comment: Here is a suggested answer for this questions:
[Suggested Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68629113/12343112)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a problem with NodeJS, the version 8 is no longer supported as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version). Deployment of functions to the Node.js 8 runtime was disabled in the Firebase CLI on December 15, 2020 and that is most likely why you are facing the 404 error.

To migrate to a newer supported version of the NodeJS runtime, use the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#upgrade-node10).

Also, I do not suspect any issue with your firebase-admin version [7.3.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java#version_730_-_11_may_2021).

Comment: You were right. The issue was with my NodeJS v8. Upgraded to node 10 works well for me.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for accepting the answer. Please upvote it also.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error, but I was already on Node 12. Also, the function was running well for years and now is crashing due to this :/

The only solution that worked for me was to change auth to admin from default to explicit passing of `service-account.json` like is described here in docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.credential#cert

Comment: This link no longer works, do you have an example of this? I'm running into the same issue as you, Node 12

Answer (score 0):

For those who are deploying to Google Cloud Functions, requirements:

- Node >= 10

Initialisation:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
Node > 10

In my case, the error appears sometimes and not often - the reason I found is doing a bulk operation asynchronously. After adding await the calls became synchronous and this issue disappeared.